# Are culinary arts on topic

Tags: discussion, questions

So I have been confused on whether I should post culinary arts on here, or on seasoned advice. I don't want to post any culinary arts related questions and get shutdown cause of them. By culinary arts I mean cake decorating, chocolate carving, tart decorating etc.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "culinary arts". We are not a general "art" site... which is why photography and music are off topic... so what do you mean, specifically?

Comment: alright I edited the post to be more specific

Comment: It probably depends to some extent on whether you're asking more about the food or the artistry. Could you add some examples that you have in mind? (Doesn't have to be a very detailed question, just a sentence or two for each.) This lets the community really think about whether that would be on topic or not.

Comment: Visiting from cooking: "culinary arts" is a general term for pretty much everything about cooking, including preparing the food. I think you actually mean the presentation aspects of cooking - decoration, plating, and so on. (This is of course pretty consistent with Catija's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on what you're looking for.

I would say that questions that center around **taste** or **flavor** or actual cooking processes don't belong here.

So, the following are bad:

- How do I make stiff icing that's not too sweet?
- Are dark or light pans better for baking?
- What is the appropriate sugar stage for making toffee?

Questions that strictly relate to an artsy decorating of something would be acceptable here:

So, these I would be fine with:

- When making a rose with fondant icing, how do you adhere the petals to each other without ruining them?
- What is an effective method for making a stencil for powdered sugar on my chocolate torte?
- I am trying to make lace icing - of powdered, gel, and water-based color, which will affect the performance of the royal icing the least?
- I can't get my fondant molds to release - how do I keep the fondant from sticking?
- When piping and flooding cookies, what is the consistency difference between the piped icing and the flood icing?

As you can see... these questions seem to mostly be about frosting... but that's probably just where my brain is. If you can give us more specific examples in your question we can address them more directly.